# Twitter Bootstrap integration in yii2

Tags: yii2

i am starting yii2. I have a theme that i want to integrate with yii2. Which of the following is useful

```
bootstrapPluginAsset
bootstrapThemeAsset
bootstrapAsset
```

How to use these in terms of js & css addition to view?

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 already comes integrated with bootstrap 3, now if you want to integrate a new theme you can take a look at how it is done here:
https://github.com/mithun12000/adminUI

Answer (score 0):

i'm usually use `bootstrapAsset` when create `AppAsset`

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

but if you want include other files for your theme, you can register it like this

```
public $css = [
    'css/example.css',
];
public $js = [
    'js/example.js'
];
```

for more information please read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html